# Azure Equivalent of AWS Athena over s3

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, amazon-athena

I have an AWS workload that stores csv files in partitions in s3 and then queries the data with SQL queries using Athena, writing the results back to s3.

I'm looking for an equivalent behavior in Azure, where I could store csv files in a storage and query them and write the results back to that storage.

Comment: it looks like "azure synapse" is similar see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-json-files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on the information provided on [`AWS to Azure services comparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services), the equivalent service in Azure is [`Azure Data Lake Analytics`](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/data-lake-analytics/). For Storage, S3 equivalent service would be [`Azure Data Lake Storage`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/data-lake-storage/) which is built on top of [`Azure Blob Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction).

[image]

Comment: is it possible to use Azure Data Lake Analytics to query data stored in Azure Blob Storage? or is is possible only if the data is stored in Azure Data Lake Storage?

Comment: I have not tried it but it should be possible. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-portal#manage-data-sources.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent service to Amazon Athena in Azure will be [Data Lake Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/data-lake-analytics/) as per this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services).

Also as per [this](https://anthonychu.ca/post/aws-reinvent-2016-announcements/) doc The Azure equivalent of Athena is Data Lake Analytics. Like Athena, it is also "serverless" and pay-per-use. It uses U-SQL, which is a combination of SQL and C# that provides a lot of power and flexibility that SQL alone cannot. An advantage of Data Lake Analytics is that it is not limited to querying Azure Data Lake Store and Blob Storage, it can also talk to SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Synapse Analytics you can query files with TSQL
https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/products/synapse-analytics/#overview

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please [add context to your link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, and then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

There are couple of things in Azure you can do read semi-structured, structured, unstructured lake files from Azure Blob Storage or Data Lake Storage like Amazon Athena Query does on top of S3 files.

1. You can use **Azure Data Explorer** with KSQL to read and do analytics on lake files. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/
2. You can use Synapse **Serverless SQL Pool** to issue TSQL to read and do analytics on Lake files using TSQL OPENROWSET - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-json-files